# float128 SVD in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, precision, svd

I have a ndarray of type `float128`. I would like to compute the SVD of this matrix, however when I used `sp.linalg.svd` the returned arrays are of type `float64`. Is there a simple way to get the computations to be done in `float128`?

If not, is it possible to directly call the LAPACK functions?

I have also seen mpmath, which I may have to use is there is no easy way to do this. Is there a simple way to use this function on my numpy array? I'm having trouble converting my `float128` to the mpmath matrix.

Comment: Has your LAPACK library been compiled for 128? It's more likely that the limitation is in that compiled code than in the Python calling it. It's even less likely that your library would work with `mpmath`.

Comment: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/faq.html#_what_is_the_naming_scheme_for_lapack_routines - LAPACK data types are REAL, DOUBLE PRECISION, and the corresponding complex types.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I believe you're right. It seems like I might have to compile the LAPACK functions with extended precision if I want to use those. As for mpmath, I would like to just convert a numpy array to a mpmath matrix so that I can use the SVD in mpmath. However I'm having issues converting an array of `float128`.

Comment: What's the problem with converting the numpy array to a `mp.matrix`?

Comment: It works fine for double and single but throws a type error if I have an array of float128. I though maybe I could get around this by converting the float128 to a string and then using that to make the mpmath matrix, but so far I'm running into issues of the float128 getting cast to double before becoming a string.

Comment: With `mpmath` v 1.1.0 and `numpy` v 1.16 I don't get an error.

Comment: When I do `mp.matrix(np.array([[1.]],dtype='float128'))` I get an error, but if I do `mp.matrix(np.array([[1.]],dtype='float64'))` it works fine? Any thoughts on why?

Comment: My combination of versions works, `matrix([['1.0']])`.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help, I'll try and dig through the errors.

Comment: I updated everything and it works now. Thank you.