# Support for float128 (np.longdouble) in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, precision, long-double

I would like to make some probability computations with `scipy.stats`, and avoid under/overflows:
in addition to using the appropriate log-functions, I tried to increase the float precision using `numpy.longdouble` (float128 on Ubuntu).

However, the functions I tried failed, for example:

```
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as st
x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5], dtype=np.longdouble)
st.entropy(x)
st.gamma.pdf(x, 2)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-72225ce02b65> in <module>
----> 1 st.entropy(x)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in entropy(pk, qk, base, axis)
   2664     pk = 1.0*pk / np.sum(pk, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
   2665     if qk is None:
-> 2666         vec = entr(pk)
   2667     else:
   2668         qk = asarray(qk)

TypeError: ufunc 'entr' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Is there any support for long double precision in `scipy.stats`?
According to this [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.types.html), it does not seem so :-(

---

#### Details and versions

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54953315/4614641), except that `scipy.linalg.svd` or `mpmath.matrix` work for me.

scipy version is 1.4.1, and `numpy.show_config()`:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no, there isn't. Select methods of specific distributions may or may not work, and it's not guaranteed.